# Using a custom domain on GAE. Won't let me past Step 4

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm trying to use a custom domain with a static site hosted on AppEngine. Once I get into Google Apps to add the domain, I just get stuck on this page. Basically, I can't get past Step 4 as per the instructions [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/domain). I click "Accept" and hit the activate button but the page just refreshes. I spent about a half hour on the phone with "Lewis" from Google phone support and he eventually told me to try App Engine support lol. During the support call we attempted to get this to work multiple times using both the latest Chrome and FF browsers with cookies/cache, etc. cleared.

No reputation, so no screenshot but like I said, the problem is at Step 4 where you have to accept GAE's terms.

Looks like similar problem [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-appengine/OmAW-tPzLMA). Anyone have the same problem and/or know of a solution? Thanks﻿

Answer (score 0):

You can try other way to activate, like a html page.
I have used this method to activate.

Comment: I didn't see any option like that - don't have a link do you?

Answer (score 0):

My activated page seems those:

> 1. By html to activate => //i.stack.imgur.com/t3nM1.png ;
> 2. By operators to activate =>//i.stack.imgur.com/fZTWH.png;

Can you see them?
*By the way, I am in China, so, these uploaded images that I can not see them.*

Comment: Hm, I can not see them either.  Thanks for trying, though.

Comment: I can send these pictures to you by email. Could you give me a message firstly.